# FontForge: How to scale a glyph

Tags: python-2.7, scale, fontforge

I have been able to batch import svg at their appropriate places, through the python scripts that come with the fontforge. Now I want to scale up each glyph let's say 200%. I am able to do that in fontforge through the

> Elements->Tranformations->Transform->choosing scale uniformly from 
>   the dropdown and entering 200%.

How can I do the same from the functions provided in the python library, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

Well Found it myself!

```
import fontforge   
import psMat   

SFD_FONT = fontforge.open("DejaVuMono.sfd") 
INDEX = 105 
SCALE_MATRIX = psMat.scale(0.50) 
print SFD_FONT[INDEX].foreground[0].boundingBox() 
SFD_FONT[INDEX].foreground[0].transform(SCALE_MATRIX) 
print SFD_FONT[INDEX].foreground[0].boundingBox()
```